# How can I call a exported function using ordinal number

Tags: windows, dll, ordinals, ordinal

If a dll exports some functions and the functions have only ordinal numbers, how can I call the functions?

Give me a short example please.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The documentation for [GetProcAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683212%28VS.85%29.aspx) explains that you pass the integer ordinal in the low-order word of the `lpProcName` parameter. The [MAKEINTRESOURCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648029%28VS.85%29.aspx) macro can actually be used to make this a little easier:

```
int ordinal = 123;
HANDLE dll = LoadLibrary("MyDLL.dll");
FARPROC fn = GetProcAddress(dll, MAKEINTRESOURCE(ordinal));
```

Comment: I don't know why this does not work in my case:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47282845/how-to-see-what-is-ordinal-x-in-my-dll

Comment: You need to call (PCSTR)ordinal in UNICODE projects.

Comment: It's actually `MAKEINTRESOURCEA(ordinal)` to make it compatible with UNICODE projects.