# vc++ dll call by vc++ application by ordinal no

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, loadlibrary

How to call vc++ dll in vc++.

in .h file

```
typedef int (*LPVAR)(char * ptr_f, char *CC);
HINSTANCE hDLL;
```

in .cpp file

```
hDLL = NULL;
LPVAR var;
hDLL = LoadLibrary("Pro.dll");


if( hDLL == NULL )
    AfxMessageBox("Could not load the DLL");
else
{
    var = (LPVAR)GetProcAddress(hDLL, "#2"); //2 is ordinal no
    char *ch,*a;
    ch = (char*)malloc(100*sizeof(char));
    a = (char*)malloc(10*sizeof(char));
    int c = var(ch,a);
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/3598125/32746

Comment: @PhilMY can you tell me how to proceed after that....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that `var` is not `NULL` after calling `GetProcAddress`.

You may have more success using [MAKEINTRESOURCE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3598125/32746), like this:

```
var = (LPVAR)GetProcAddress(hDLL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(2));
```

Remember to call `free` for the pointers returned by `malloc`, and call [FreeLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683152(v=vs.85).aspx) when you have finished with `hDLL`.

Comment: Yes after that var is not null but after calling var, int c not update

Comment: Have you checked the [calling convention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/984x0h58.aspx) of the DLL? You might need to add one of those keywords to your `typedef`.