# how to see what is ordinal x in my dll

Tags: c++, windows, dll, ordinal

The client has reported me that my dll gives "ordinal 5 not located" error when loading it. To see what ordinal 5 is, I have found this:

[How can I call a exported function using ordinal number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598108/how-can-i-call-a-exported-function-using-ordinal-number)

But the example in the answer of there gives me error.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <winuser.h>
#include <winbase.h>

int main()
{
    const wchar_t str[200] = 
    L"D:\\mydll.dll";
    HANDLE mydll = LoadLibrary(str);

    int ordinal = 5;
    FARPROC fn = GetProcAddress(mydll, MAKEINTRESOURCE(ordinal));

    return 0;
}
```

The error is:

> main.cpp:15: error: invalid conversion from 'HANDLE {aka void*}' to
>   'HMODULE {aka HINSTANCE__*}' [-fpermissive]
>        FARPROC fn = GetProcAddress(mydll, MAKEINTRESOURCE(ordinal));
>
> main.cpp:15: error: cannot convert 'LPWSTR {aka > wchar_t*}' to
>   'LPCSTR {aka const char*}' for argument '2' to 'int
>   (**attribute**((**stdcall**)) * GetProcAddress(HMODULE, LPCSTR))()'
>   FARPROC fn = GetProcAddress(mydll, MAKEINTRESOURCE(ordinal));

Any idea on what I am trying to do?
How can I find what is problem with loading my dll? What is ordinal 5?

Comment: `HMODULE mydll = LoadLibrary(str);`

Comment: @RbMm This removes the first error and the second has remained.

Comment: Short fix: `HMODULE mydll = LoadLibraryW(str);`. Proper fix: define `UNICODE` and `_UNICODE` for your project, if working with `wchar_t`s.

Comment: What about the second part? The first parameter ok, but I could not make MAKEINTRESOURCE(ordinal)  work.

Comment: Try `MAKEINTRESOURCEA(ordinal)` instead.