# Exporting a C++ Function from a dll without extern "C"

Tags: c++, dllexport

Objective: 
Application should be able to load a dll dynamically using LoadLibrary and call its exported function using GetProcAddress.

My dll class has a function returning a unique_ptr of the class type.

I want to export this function such that the application can call this function using getProcAddress after dll is loaded successfully.

Using extern "C" will not allow to use a C++ class(unique_ptr class template, in this case) in the function signature.

I know, If do not use extern "C", it will export the function ( via __declspec(dllexport) ) with a mangled name.

The client will not know the mangled name during the call to getProcAddress, so how will a client call this function?

Is there a way to export such a function?

Comment: "Is there a way to export such a function?" Of course, but only if you're willing to use the mangled/decorated name when using `GetProcAddress`. And that you use it from a C++ program where you can actually create the objects of the C++ classes.

Comment: I dont want to use the mangled names, as that will force my client application to be built using the same compiler as my dll. And, yes, the client is a C++ application and hence there is no issue in exporting the c++ class as return type.

Comment: @user2100866: Your client application is already forced to use the same compiler, `std::unique_ptr`  is implementation-dependent.

Comment: While the mangled name is compiler-dependent, you can still use it in a program compiled by a different compiler for simple functions. The problem comes with differences in ABI and object implementations.

Comment: @user2100866 "*that will force my client application to be built using the same compiler as my dll*" - sorry, but that is a requirement no matter what you do, since your function returns a class type that depends on a specific implementation. That is not portable across compilers. "*And, yes, the client is a C++ application and hence there is no issue in exporting the c++ class as return type*" - yes, there is. The DLL and client MUST be compiled with the same compiler, and even the same standard library, to ensure the same implementation of the class, as well as the memory manager, is used...

Comment: @user2100866 ... The binary layout of the class, and its runtime behaviors, between the DLL and client must be compatible . And you can't `new` memory inside the DLL and `delete` it inside the client app if they don't share the same memory manager. Just because the DLL and client are both compiled in any C++ compilers does not guarantee that. Even using the same compiler does not guarantee that.

Comment: Tip: You can also provide a pair of old-fashioned C functions in the DLL, and a C++ header which wraps that in code compiler by the customer's choice of C++ compiler. `std::unique_ptr` supports custom deleters, which would be the second C function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the old-fashioned way. Looking up functions by name is the "modern" way (although it predates Windows 95). The old way is to look them up [by ordinal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598108/how-can-i-call-a-exported-function-using-ordinal-number).

You'll need to provide a [module definition file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/module-definition-dot-def-files?view=vs-2019) with `EXPORTS` to number your functions.

Comment: I tried using the ordinal number and it worked. One thing I did not understand is that why do we need a def file, is it just for the client to know the number for the function it wants to call? What if I am sure that there will be only one exported function, in that case, can I get rid of def file and use the ordinal number 1(as a hard coded value).  I tried this and it worked, so just wanted to be sure about it.

Comment: Given that it's 25 year old technology, I wouldn't expect sudden changes :D If it works now, it's likely to work for the next 25 years.

Answer (score 1):

> Using extern "C" will not allow to use a C++ class(unique_ptr class template, in this case) in the function signature

This is simply not true. Export any signature you like with `extern "C"`. Classes, references, whatever. It just [works](https://godbolt.org/z/sfvM947Gd).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to export a C++ function from a DLL without using `extern "C"`, you can still achieve it by using a technique called name decoration or name mangling. Name decoration modifies the function name in a specific way based on the function signature and other factors.

To allow the client to call the function using `GetProcAddress` without knowing the mangled name, you can use a technique called name export forwarding. With this approach, you create a separate C-style wrapper function that has a well-known name and calls the actual C++ function internally.

Here's an example of how you can export a C++ function from a DLL and provide a C-style wrapper for the client to use:

```
// DLL header file
#ifdef MYLIB_EXPORTS
#define MYLIB_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define MYLIB_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

// Forward declaration of C-style wrapper function
extern "C" MYLIB_API void entryPoint_wrapper();

// Actual C++ function definition
MYLIB_API void entryPoint();

// C-style wrapper function implementation
void entryPoint_wrapper()
{
    entryPoint();
}
```

With this approach, the client can call the `entryPoint_wrapper` function using `GetProcAddress` with the known name `entryPoint_wrapper`. The wrapper function will internally call the actual `entryPoint` function.

Please note that you need to export both the C++ function (`entryPoint`) and the C-style wrapper function (`entryPoint_wrapper`) from the DLL using `__declspec(dllexport)`.

Comment: This completely eliminates the idea of the author's post. The idea is to have a C++ return type, or possibly C++ objects as parameters. This, in your example, will not work, as the client has stated.