# How to link IUnknown_QueryServicePropertyBag

Tags: c++, winapi, undocumented-behavior

Let's say there's an undocumented Winapi function you'd like to use, like [`IUnknown_QueryServicePropertyBag`](https://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/windows/shell/shlwapi/api/util/iunknown/queryservicepropertybag.htm).  I was wondering how you go about using it.  It seems like declaring it isn't a big deal, if you have the function signature.  But then what about linking it?  How is that done?  Thanks for any advice.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3598108/how-can-i-call-a-exported-function-using-ordinal-number

Comment: link with *OneCore.Lib*