# How to call SHCreateMemStream() directly from ordinal 12

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I'm writing an app that still needs to run on Windows XP. I want to use `SHCreateMemStream()`. MSDN says this:

> Prior to Windows Vista, this function was not included in the public
> Shlwapi.h file, nor was it exported by name from Shlwapi.dll. To use
> it on earlier systems, you must call it directly from the Shlwapi.dll
> file as ordinal 12
> ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-shcreatememstream))

But how do I do that? Since MSDN says that `SHCreateMemStream()` is not exported by name in `Shlwapi.dll` I guess I can't just use `LoadLibrary()` and `GetProcAddress()` to get a function pointer to it on XP. So how am I supposed to call this function on XP?

Note that I'm looking for a solution in plain C, not C++.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3598108/10871073) help?

Comment: simply link with *Shlwapi.lib* - here anyway *SHCreateMemStream* imported by ordinal 12

Comment: "*I guess I can't just use `LoadLibrary()` and `GetProcAddress()` to get a function pointer to it on XP*" - yes, you can. `GetProcAddress()` can lookup a function by name **or ordinal**.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Thanks, I didn't know that. But it turns out that the link lib that comes with the Windows 7 SDK also imports the ordinal (as pointed out by RbMm in his answer). So the note in MSDN quoted in my OP is probably a relic from very old SDKs because in the Windows 7 SDK there's really nothing special to be done for `SHCreateMemStream()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not need something special for xp. as usual link with *Shlwapi.lib* and call *SHCreateMemStream* as any imported api. all *Shlwapi.lib* from ms sdk import *SHCreateMemStream* by ordinal 12 but not by name (this can be checked by run

```
link.exe /dump /exports <path>shlwapi.lib > shlwapi.txt
```

if all ok, you must view inside shlwapi.txt (of course you can select any name for output file)

```
Dump of file <path>shlwapi.lib

File Type: LIBRARY

     Exports

       ordinal    name

       ...

            12    _SHCreateMemStream@8
       ...
```

in output will be list of functions imported by this *lib*. before some names printed ordinal - this mean that this function imported by ordinal. in no ordinal - function imported by name. *SHCreateMemStream* imported by ordinal 12. so if you link with such lib - your *PE* will be import *SHCreateMemStream* by ordinal 12, but not by name. this you and need.

Comment: You're right, it works. Compiled on Windows 7 with the Windows 7 SDK and it works just fine on XP. Thanks!